# Integral of $\sqrt{ax-x^2}$

Tags: integration

Can we integrate a function of the form $$\sqrt{ax-x^2},\text{say for any limits a to b}$$
I was solving a question recently where I had to find the volume and the eqn of base was $$x^2+y^2=ax\implies\,(x-\frac{a}{2})^2+y^2=\frac{a^2}{4}$$
now although it is easy to integrate this when writing x in terms of y, i tried to write y in terms of x and got the equation written above and was stuck as to how to integrate that form

Comment: $\sqrt{ax-x^2}$ is not an equation – it is lacking that basic possession of every equation, an equals sign. But, yes, there is an elementary antiderivative. Search for "trigonometric substitutions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Try the following:

\begin{align*}
ax-x^{2} &=-(x^{2}-ax) \\
&= \frac{a^{2}}{4}-(x^{2}-ax+\frac{a^{2}}{4})\\
&= \frac{a^2}{4}-\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2}
\end{align*}

Then try substituting $x-\frac{a}{2}=\frac{a}{2}\sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint***

Substitute $x=a\cos^2(u)$

with $dx=-2a\cos(u)\sin(u) du =-a\sin(2u)du $

$\sqrt{ax-x^2}=\sqrt {a^2\cos^2(u)-a^2\cos^4(u)}=a \cos(u)\sin(u)=\frac a 2 \sin(2u)$

then,

$$I=\frac {-a^2} 2 \int \sin^2(2u)du$$